Why does the chronology of Smith's The Fraud jump about?
Zadie Smith's The Fraud (New York: Penguin, 2023) is historical fiction about the novelist William Harrison Ainsworth and the Tichborne Case. The story is told largely from the point of view of Ainsworth's cousin and housekeeper Eliza Touchet. At one point she takes an interest in Andrew Bogle, one of the Tichborne family servants who vouched for the identity of the Tichborne claimant. Bogle had previously been a slave in Jamaica.
About a quarter of the novel consists of Bogle's life history as he tells it to Touchet. This long section, chronologically told, is framed by Eliza's story: her difficult marriage, the loss of her husband and child, her involvement with the novelist and his family, her involvement in the abolitionist movement, her interest in the Tichborne case, and her observations of the literary milieu surrounding Ainsworth (Dickens and Thackeray are among the characters). Her story, however, is told in disjointed fashion. Brief chapters (sometimes only a paragraph long) narrate incidents from the 1820s to the 1880s. Sometimes these are presented as her recollections, sometimes as the narrative present. This jagged chronology makes for difficult reading: it is not always easy to know when a given incident is taking place. Additionally, some chapters consist of reproductions of primary sources such as the first page of one of Ainsworth's novels, transcripts from the Tichborne trials, etc.
The narrative technique employed for Eliza Touchet's story, i.e., intercut episodes over six decades, contrasts sharply with the straightforwardly linear narration for Albert Bogle's as he relates it to Eliza. What is the reason for this contrast? Why does the chronology jump about for Eliza's frame story, but not for Bogle's embedded narrative? What is the narrative purpose behind this structural choice?
I'm hoping for an analysis of how this furthers the themes of the novel; a pointer to what readers, critics, and scholars have had to say about Smith's use of this technique; a discussion of Smith's use of this technique vis-à-vis other contemporary writers; or some combination of these. This question is tagged interpretation so even an answer that cites no sources other than The Fraud, would be great, as long as it does engage with the novel in a specific way.
